# Laravel Linkroute does not interpret HTML but outputs as text

Tags: css, image, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I wouldn't want to have a wrong conclusion that Laravel does not have a way of using image as a link.

I have tried many methods, but none seems to work, which leaves me with a surprise. I like Laravel, I'll admit I haven't only gotten the right way to make it do it.

I'd thought this will format the HTML to present the image but it only outputs the HTML syntax as a text, what better way can I achieve this? Running out of patience, please help.

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('updateUserContact', '<img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain" src="' . asset('images/update.jpg') . '"/>', $contacts->id) !!}
```

This is the screenshot of the output:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the benefit for you to use `Html::linkRoute` instead of simply doing something like this?

```
<a href="{{ route('updateUserContact', [$contacts->id]) }}">
    <img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain" src="{{ asset('images/update.jpg') }}"/>
</a>
```

Comment: You got me exposed to a working route type. I've not used this before. A bunch of thanks.